# changing for loop to block parition

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I want to change the for-loop to block scheme

I have this for loop that does this:
let say n = 8
and node = 4

> n:   [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
>
> id:   0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3

```
id = 0;
while (id < node){
for (i = id + 1; i <= n; i = i + node)
     {
         //do stuff here
         id = i; 
     }enter code here
id+1;
}//end while
```

and i want it to do this:

n = 8
node= 4

> n:   [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
>
> id:   0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3

n = 16
node = 4

> n:   [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8] ... [13][14][15][16]
>
> id:   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1 ...    3   3    3   3

n = 8
node= 2

> n:   [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
>
> id:   0  0  0  0 1  1  1  1

where each id is assign to the top n show in examples

I have this but it only works for the specific scenario n= 8 & node = 4

```
...
b = id + 1
for (i = n-(n-(id+b)); i <= (n-(n-(id+b))+1); i+= 1)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int node = 4;
int n = 16;
for (id = 0; id < node; id++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n / node; j++) {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Or you can use this code:

```
int node = 4;
int n = 16;
for (int i = 0; i < node; i++) {
    id = i;
    for(int j = 0; j < n / node; j++) {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

They do the same.

Comment: Why not just use `id` in the first for loop?

Comment: No I mean why not replace `i` with `id`. Why declare another variable `i` at all?

Comment: thank you but it didn't worked. it assigned each id to 0-3. going to tested with the new code

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: n: [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8] ... [13][14][15][16]

id: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ... 3 3 3 3

This is part of your question. It works in the same way

Comment: it did't worked. the problem was with id. i have another part of the code that increments id on it own.

Comment: Should I change to another loop variable?

Comment: I really don't know. I can't really change id cause another part of the code does it, and I cant change what is inside the for loop. The problem is on the for loop. Side note: i'm trying to write a MPI parallel program

Comment: Then use i insead of id. And why did you use id in your examples?

Comment: I used it for illustration purposes.

Comment: In this case answer if for illustration purposes too. I do not know what variables you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I perhaps misunderstood your question but this gives the output for id as you described:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        id = i / (n / node);
        // do stuff
    }
```

I use n starting from 0, but if you start from 1, just adjust the calculation by ofsetting everything to n-1.